# PHP SQL Inner Join or Union

Tags: mysql

I want to select different fields from two different tables My users table and my address table as shown below:

my users table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `ID` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `AccountNumber` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` text NOT NULL,
  `LastName` text NOT NULL,
  `EmailAddress` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `AccountNumber` (`AccountNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

INSERT INTO `users` (`ID`, `AccountNumber`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `EmailAddress`, `Password`) VALUES
(1, 123456, 'test', 'test', 'test@test.ac.uk', '$2y$10$/j9nTE5ugmyrWuV8VNWFxe5iHInqyaTwxt5wDaxyQwPUZTDDjqNKm');
```

my address table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `address` (
  `AddID` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `HouseNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `StreetName` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `City` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Postcode` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `AccountNumber` int(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AddID`),
  KEY `AccountNumber` (`AccountNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

INSERT INTO `address` (`AddID`, `HouseNumber`, `StreetName`, `City`, `Postcode`, `AccountNumber`) VALUES
(1, 123, 'Some Road', 'someCity', 'b66', 123456);

ALTER TABLE `address`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `address_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`AccountNumber`) REFERENCES `users` (`AccountNumber`);
```

Ive manage to use the following inner join successfully:

```
SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN address ON users.AccountNumber=address.AccountNumber
```

However that also seems to retrieve the auto incremented ID's as well as the password field which i dont want.

I tried union but kept getting the error about different number of columns. How would i change my select statement to only retrieve the FirstName, LastName and EmailAddress from the users table and the HouseNumber, Street, City and Postcode from the address table based on the account number stored in both tables.

Any info will be appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: I think you should use table alias and select specific columns in place of doing `SELECT *`

Comment: by alias do you mean along the lines of `users.FirstName, users.LastName` etc etc. i tried that but kept getting some errors

Comment: Can you update your question with that updated SELECT query and the exact error that you were getting ?

Comment: Don't use 'SELECT *'. Ever. Always name the columns you actually want returned.

Comment: @strawberry yeah my bad. It was just for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of select *, just list out the columns youd like

```
SELECT u.FirstName,u.LastName,u.EmailAddress,a.HouseNumber,a.StreetName,a.City,a.Postcode 
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN address a 
ON u.AccountNumber=a.AccountNumber
```

from there you can add a where statement if you want to limit it down to one AccountNumber:

```
SELECT u.FirstName,u.LastName,u.EmailAddress,a.HouseNumber,a.StreetName,a.City,a.Postcode 
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN address a 
ON u.AccountNumber=a.AccountNumber 
WHERE u.AccountNumber=12345
```

Comment: The second statement you posted. Would that work with a session variable for the Where clause. for example if i did something like `.. WHERE u.AccountNumber = $_SESSION['loggedinuser']` ?

Comment: @Spud91 yes that would work. You might want to use prepared statements and parameterized queries for that case.

Comment: yes, just be sure you real escape your variable before putting it into your sql statement

Comment: I know how to real escape a string but not sure how to real escape a variable using pdo. Would it be the same way?

Comment: Real escaping is irrelevant if you use prepared statements

Answer (score 2):

Try this u will get the result

```
SELECT FirstName,LastName,EmailAddress,HouseNumber, 
Street, City, Postcode FROM users 
INNER JOIN address ON users.AccountNumber=address.AccountNumber
```